# How to describe table in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to describe a table in SQL Server 2008 like what we can do with the `DESC` command in Oracle.

I have table `[EX].[dbo].[EMP_MAST]` which I want to describe, but it does not work.

Error shown:

> The object 'EMP_MAST' does not exist in database 'master' or is
>   invalid for this operation.

Comment: You need to be sure to be in the **right** database in SQL Server Management Studio when you do this - you seem to be in `master` which doesn't have such a table....

Comment: @marc_s  [EX].[dbo].[EMP_MAST]  ..ts is my database structure ... DB NAME _ DBO_TABLENAME ..

Answer (score 41, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://ss64.com/ora/desc.html):

> DESC MY_TABLE
>
> is equivalent to
>
> SELECT column_name "Name", nullable "Null?",
>   concat(concat(concat(data_type,'('),data_length),')') "Type" FROM
>   user_tab_columns WHERE table_name='TABLE_NAME_TO_DESCRIBE';

I've roughly translated that to the SQL Server equivalent for you - just make sure you're running it on the `EX` database.

```
SELECT column_name AS [name],
       IS_NULLABLE AS [null?],
       DATA_TYPE + COALESCE('(' + CASE WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH = -1
                                  THEN 'Max'
                                  ELSE CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(5))
                                  END + ')', '') AS [type]
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
WHERE  table_name = 'EMP_MAST'
```

Comment: thanx man...   it works fine ...thanx a lot ...

But i have one query regarding " sp_columns " .. Why it can't works here ?

Comment: What do you mean why can't it work here? Running `exec sp_columns EMP_MAST` should return the same information, just in a different format. You also can't choose which columns you get back from the stored procedure!

Answer (score 88):

You can use [sp_columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176077.aspx), a system stored procedure for describing a table.

```
exec sp_columns TableName
```

You can also use [sp_help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187335%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Comment: sp_columns show master table structure  like TABLEVIEWER,TABLEOWNER etc

Answer (score 30):

The sp_help built-in procedure is the SQL Server's closest thing to Oracle's DESC function IMHO

```
sp_help MyTable
```

Use

```
sp_help "[SchemaName].[TableName]"
```

or

```
sp_help "[InstanceName].[SchemaName].[TableName]"
```

in case you need to qualify the table name further

Comment: Thanks Daniel, the quickness to type this and amount of info I get back wins it for me.

Answer (score 9):

You can use keyboard short-cut for Description/ detailed information of Table in `SQL Server 2008`.

### Follow steps:

1. Write Table Name,
2. Select it, and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> **+** <kbd>F1</kbd>
3. It will show detailed information/ description of mentioned table as,

   1) Table created date,
   2) Columns Description,
   3) Identity,
   4) Indexes,
   5) Constraints,
   6) References etc. As shown Below [*example*]:

[image: Alt+F1 Demo]

Answer (score 8):

May be this can help:

```
Use MyTest
Go
select * from information_schema.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME='employee'
```

{ where: MyTest= DatabaseName
       Employee= TableName } --Optional conditions

Answer (score 6):

I like the answer that attempts to do the translate, however, while using the code it doesn't like columns that are not VARCHAR type such as BIGINT or DATETIME.  I needed something similar today so I took the time to modify it more to my liking.  It is also now encapsulated in a function which is the closest thing I could find to just typing describe as oracle handles it.  I may still be missing a few data types in my case statement but this works for everything I tried it on.  It also orders by ordinal position.  this could be expanded on to include primary key columns easily as well.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.describe (@TABLENAME varchar(50))
returns table
as
RETURN
(
SELECT TOP 1000 column_name AS [ColumnName],
       IS_NULLABLE AS [IsNullable],
       DATA_TYPE + '(' + CASE 
                                    WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'varchar' or DATA_TYPE = 'char' THEN 
                                      CASE 
                                        WHEN Cast(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(5)) = -1 THEN 'Max'
                                        ELSE Cast(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(5))
                                      END
                                    WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'decimal' or DATA_TYPE = 'numeric' THEN
                                      Cast(NUMERIC_PRECISION AS VARCHAR(5))+', '+Cast(NUMERIC_SCALE AS VARCHAR(5))
                                    WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'bigint' or DATA_TYPE = 'int' THEN
                                      Cast(NUMERIC_PRECISION AS VARCHAR(5))
                                    ELSE ''
                                  END + ')' AS [DataType]
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
WHERE  table_name = @TABLENAME
order by ordinal_Position
);
GO
```

once you create the function here is a sample table that I used

```
create table dbo.yourtable
(columna bigint,
 columnb int,
 columnc datetime,
 columnd varchar(100),
 columne char(10),
 columnf bit,
 columng numeric(10,2),
 columnh decimal(10,2)
 )
```

Then you can execute it as follows

```
select * from describe ('yourtable')
```

It returns the following

ColumnName  IsNullable  DataType

---

columna     NO          bigint(19)
columnb     NO          int(10)
columnc     NO          datetime()
columnd     NO          varchar(100)
columne     NO          char(10)
columnf     NO          bit()
columng     NO          numeric(10, 2)
columnh     NO          decimal(10, 2)

hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

As a variation of Bridge's answer (I don't yet have enough rep to comment, and didn't feel right about editing that answer), here is a version that works better for me.

```
SELECT column_name AS [Name],
   IS_NULLABLE AS [Null?],
   DATA_TYPE + CASE
                 WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS NULL THEN ''
                 WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH > 99999 THEN ''
                 ELSE '(' + Cast(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')' 
               END AS [Type]
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns
WHERE  table_name = 'table_name'
```

Notable changes:

- Works for **types without length**.  For an int column, I was seeing    NULL for the type because the length was null and it wiped out the    whole Type column.  So don't print any length component (or parens).
- Change the check for *CAST* length of -1 to **check actual length**.  I was getting a syntax error because the case resulted in '*' rather than -1.  Seems to make more sense to perform an arithmetic check rather than an overflow from the CAST.
- **Don't print length when very long** (arbitrarily > 5 digits).

Answer (score 2):

Just enter the below line.

```
exec sp_help [table_name]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Sure . Thanks for the suggestion. Will add context as well from next time.