# Not able to use DESC command in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

I have SQL Server 2012 Management Studio. I am trying to create tables using commands.

After creating the table, I try to use the `DESC` command to view the table structure but it shows error saying

> incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DESC'.

The statement is:

```
DESC doughnut_list;
```

Comment: DESC is an ORACLE command. maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078106/how-to-describe-table-in-sql-server-2008) will be helpful for you

Comment: What are you expecting DESC to do? (It's an abbreviation for "DESCENDING" in SQL Server; it's not DESCribe like it is in Oracle utilities...) SQL Server is generally more visual and GUI-based, though there are underlying functions for looking at table structure. (Try expanding the table in the object list in the sidebar of SSMS; this is typically what a SQL Server user would do to quickly examine the table.)

Answer (score 9):

You may try to use it like this:-

```
exec sp_columns doughnut_list
```

DESC is not an SQL command, it is used in Oracle. You may also try to check [sp_columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176077.aspx)

Also if you want to view the table defintion you may try use this:

```
EXEC sp_help doughnut_list
```

or may be use a short cut by selecting the table and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> key

**On a side note:-**

In Sql Server **DESC** is the short form of **DESCending**.

In Oracle it is the short form of **DESCribe**.

Comment: @user2974748:- You are welcome! If the answer helped you may accept this as an answer as well!

Answer (score 3):

For example : If your table name is CUSTOMERS. Type your Table name as CUSTOMERS in (sql server) query form and select it. Now press<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Your table structure will be displayed completely.

Answer (score 2):

`DESC` is not an SQL command, it's an SQL*Plus function - i.e., it won't work on other tools, especially if they are used to mange non-oracle databases.

You can use `EXEC sp_help 'my_table'` as a way of getting a comparable functionality.

Comment: that answers the problem

Answer (score 2):

You can right click on the table and select:

Script Table As > Create To > New Query Editor Window

The resulting create script will contain the exact table description that you are used to seeing using the SQL Desc command. You can view/copy the field descriptions from there.

Cheers
LD

Comment: Simplest answer and actually most powerful one ;)

Answer (score 2):

`EXEC sp_help 'mytable';`
this can not be desc the table this only to show all data of the table
fuad alhagami

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should also be able to see the attribute names simply by expanding the table name, click the + sign on the LHS of the table and you should be able to see the attribute names. correct me if m wrong m also new to sql server management studio.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SQL server2012: Right click on the corresponding Table and click on "Design" link. This will publish the complete Table structure.