# mssql_bind to SQLVARCHAR not bringing back the full contents of the database field

Tags: php, sql-server

I've got a PHP form that stores information in a SQL Server database, using SQLTEXT to bind. The content is correctly stored in the database, but when I try to retrieve the information to display a printable copy of the submitted information back to the user I get an error using SQLTEXT. Instead of using that data type I've used SQLVARCHAR, but I'm only getting a 241 characters back.

To retrieve the content I'm binding using:
    mssql_bind($statement, "@SPVaraible", $exportvariable, SQLVARCHAR, TRUE);

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried using the final `$maxlen` argument to [`mssql_bind()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-bind.php)?

Comment: I've tried this, but no joy so far. I presume this has to match the length of the database field? I'm waiting for the database developer to get back to me with that info.

Comment: You should be able to retrieve this information from the database yourself, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319354/what-is-the-equivalent-of-describe-table-in-mssql

Answer (score 0):

Please read [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-bind.php) for mssql_bind, you can define maxlen for SQLVARCHAR.