# Why does sp_columns return no results?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to "describe" a table for a different post I have on StackOverflow, but when I run sp_columns, no results or rows are shown.

```
sp_columns assignee
```

Results:

```
A bunch of column headers...
```

What's wrong with my database, and why doesn't this work?

Comment: What's with the downvotes? If the Q is bad, at least say why or edit it to make it better.

Comment: Wasn't me, but a suspicion: your question is very basic and was because you were connected to the wrong database (user error). The question is unlikely to be valuable to future readers.

Comment: Basic though it may be, we've got more than 1,000 views on it now.

Comment: 1,000 whole views! In 9 months! Whoa! Did it make the front page of Reddit or Hacker News? Does view count somehow indicate quality?

Comment: Meh, that's 1,000 people that found it useful. That's pretty good in my book. Perhaps we have differing views of popular/useful.

Comment: Again, viewing a page does not mean they found your question useful. It just means they found it. A good judge of whether they found it useful would be if all 1,000+ people had up-voted it. Since only 3 did...

Comment: (Also interesting to note, if you hadn't made a fuss about this 9 months later, you wouldn't have had a bunch of new eyes seeing your question and still not finding it useful. Funny that none of the new viewers up-voted the question; they must not have found it useful either. You did view the tool-tip on the up- and down-vote buttons, right?)

Comment: Jeesh, the sarcasm isn't necessary or helpful ("you did look at the tool-tip on the up- and down-vote buttons, right?" -- common, man, I don't care how much rep you have, be nice). I'm just saying that a bunch of people have looked at this and some found it useful -- most questions don't get any upvotes at all, so I'm happy with the three it got so far. There's a place for basic questions too. Didn't realize I was stirring some hornet's nest.

Comment: I did start out as pretty nice. Just saw no reason for you to come back 9 months later and try to rub it in my face that it got 1000 views therefore it must be a good question. Those two things don't necessarily have anything at all to do with each other, nor do I care...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of `sp_columns` use catalog views (many of these `sp_` procedures are not updated for new features).

```
SELECT name, system_type_id, ...
  FROM sys.columns
  WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableName');
  ---- yes this is important ----^^^^
```

Also, make sure you're in the right database, obviously.

Answer (score 3):

For a specific schema, try:

```
sp_columns tableName, schemaName
```

Answer (score 2):

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA is ANSI standard.

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'MEMBER_FLAGS'
;

SELECT COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,NUMERIC_PRECISION,NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'MEMBER_FLAGS'
;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're connected to the wrong database, the query will execute without error, but will not return any results.

For example, if you have a table called `assignee` in the `patents` database and are running this query against the `master` database, you'll get no results and no error:

```
sp_columns 'dbo.assignee';
```

Results:

```
Nothing, nada, zilch.
```

If you change your connection so the query applies to the correct database, you'll get results.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I don't know why but `EXEC sp_columns 'dbo.tablename';` returns an empty set for me, even though `EXEC sp_help 'dbo.tablename'` works fine. *Edit:* `EXEC sp_columns 'tablename', 'dbo'` works! (Also without the quotes)

Comment: @AndriyM what version of SQL Server? Anyway if you can't get `sp_columns` to work, all the more reason to stop using the `sp_` procedures and use `sys.columns` instead (or, on 2012, the mew metadata discovery functions/procedures). Especially if you have tables in schemas other than `dbo` - just try to do a lot of this stuff in AdventureWorks; good luck.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM. I've never used `sp_columns`, was just taking a look at it for my own education. It was `sp_helptext sp_columns` that revealed the correct method of using the proc to me, but I agree with you and will probably never actually need to use `sp_columns`.

Comment: I couldn't replicate your result. My server didn't return `Nothing, nada, zilch.` ... please help this is urgent issue I could get fired.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below,

```
exec sp_columns yourTableName
```

This will Return column information for the specified tables and views that can be queried in the current environment.

note: If table contains data then you will only get list of data.