# What is wrong with this specific t-sql query for a table located on a linked Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have this following simple t-sql query which lists all the columns and their relevant data types from a table on my local database.

```
USE [MyDatabase]

exec sp_columns [Table1]
```

I want to query that same Table which is located on a linked server. However, there must be something wrong in my query as I am getting an "incorrect syntax" error:

```
USE [MyDatabase]

exec sp_columns [Server IP].[Database Name on linked Server].dbo.[Table1]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you can try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-columns-ex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks. I tried this based on the example on that web page but it's not working: 
EXEC sp_columns_ex   'Server IP',   
  'Table1',   
  'Database Name'

Comment: What does `select * from [Server IP].[Database Name on linked Server].sys.columns` return?

Comment: @Charlieface Without the Table Name in the query?

Comment: You could join it to `sys.tables` to filter it `select c.* from [Server IP].[Database Name on linked Server].sys.columns c join [Server IP].[Database Name on linked Server].sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id and t.name = 'Table1'`

Comment: @Charlieface I ran it as you said and it appears to list the columns of all tables found on the database. I got 29,743 rows.

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks. Runs fine. Is it possible to have the datatype listed in a column?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your lack of quotes, you aren't making your value a literal string. This can be easily replicated without a linked server:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable (ID int);
GO
EXEC sys.sp_columns MyTable;
GO
EXEC sys.sp_columns dbo.MyTable;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable;
```

The first call to `sys.sp_columns` works fine, as the literal `MyTable` is interpreted as a literal string, per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> If you pass a single word that does not begin with @ and that's not enclosed in quotation marks - for example, if you forget @ on a parameter name - the word is treated as an nvarchar string, in spite of the missing quotation marks.

So `MyTable` is treated as `N'MyTable'`. For the latter call, this is not true. This is also documented (per the above), and also explicitly called out for object names:

> If the value of a parameter is an object name, character string, or qualified by a database name or schema name, **the whole name must be enclosed in single quotation marks**. If the value of a parameter is a keyword, the keyword must be enclosed in double quotation marks.

Emphasis mine. You aren't quoting your string, so it errors.

> Incorrect syntax near '.'.

So, for the above, quote your strings. It's literally that simple:

```sql
EXEC sp_columns N'dbo.MyTable';
```

Comment: Thanks. I gave it a try but it's still throwing an error. The quote should be only for 'dbo.Table1' ?

Comment: *"The quote should be only for 'dbo.Table1' ?"* ***"the WHOLE name must be enclosed in single quotation marks"*** @user3115933 ...

Comment: Ok. I tried this but still not working:
exec sp_columns N 'xxx.xx.x.20.HMS.dbo.Table1'

Comment: `N'xxx.xx.x.20.HMS.dbo.Table1` has 7 parts, @user3115933 ... You can't have more than 4 parts. `[Server Name].[Database Name].[Schema Name].[Object Name]`. Presumably you have created an object with `.`'s in the its name; a very poor decision I am afraid. You need to delimit identify the object with the non standard name.

Comment: *I'm* guessing the first 4 "paats" is actually an IP, so perhaps `N'[xxx.xx.x.20].HMS.dbo.Table1'`.

Comment: The first 4 parts is the IP Address of the Server...

Comment: Yes, that's what I assumed in my above [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69672978/what-is-wrong-with-this-specific-t-sql-query-for-a-table-located-on-a-linked-ser/69673307#comment123153403_69673307).

Comment: So, I'm out of luck here?

Comment: ... No, Delimit Identify the OBject name with `.`s in it... You literally did this in your question; I don't know why you've removed them.

Comment: I literally demonstrate it in my [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69672978/what-is-wrong-with-this-specific-t-sql-query-for-a-table-located-on-a-linked-ser/69673307#comment123153403_69673307) too. iIf you're still getting errors, however, then you should be posting a new question, as this answer address why you have a syntax error. If you now can't connect to the linked server, that is a very different problem.

Comment: the square brackets,you mean?

Comment: Yes, @user3115933, **delimit identify** the object name(s) that must be delimit identified.

Comment: See [Database Identifiers- Classes of Identifiers: Delimited identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15#classes-of-identifiers) @user3115933 .

Comment: Still having incorrect syntax error:
exec sp_columns N '[xxx.xx.x.20].[HMS].dbo.[Table1]'

Comment: ..,. `N '[xxx.xx.x.20].[HMS].dbo.[Table1]'` <> `N'[xxx.xx.x.20].[HMS].dbo.[Table1]'` @user3115933 ... There is no space between `N` and `'`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now, it does run but does not give any output (0 records)

Comment: I can't answer that with the inforamtion we have and that's a different question, @user3115933 .

Comment: Though, in truth @user3115933 , as per the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966329/why-does-sp-columns-return-no-results) you would likely be better off using the `sys.column` object. But if you have trouble implementing that, that too should be a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the system tables via the normal Linked Server name

```
select
  typename = typ.name,
  c.*
from [Server IP].[Database Name on linked Server].sys.columns c
join [Server IP].[Database Name on linked Server].sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id
join [Server IP].[Database Name on linked Server].sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = t.schema_id
join [Server IP].[Database Name on linked Server].sys.types typ on typ.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
where t.name = 'Table1'
  and s.name = 'SchemaName'
```