# Get Description of Columns Returned

Tags: c#, sql-server

In SQL Server and/or its C# API, is there a mechanism by which I can get a description (i.e. column names and data types) of the result of executing arbitrary SQL/prepared statement/stored procedure without actually executing it?

Example...

```
select * from my my_table
```

Desired result...

```
col_1        col_2        col_3        ...        col_n
integer      float        varchar(32)             datetime2
```

Or some equivalent information?

Comment: In SQL Server, check the views in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, as in `select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'some table name'`

Comment: Does this work arbitrary select statements, prepared statements, stored procedures, etc?

Comment: There's a view for procedures/triggers/functions called `ROUTINES` under this schema, but i don't think it takes care of arbitrary statements and stuff like that, but it helps a little

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SET FMTONLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx) is what you're looking for:

> Returns only metadata to the client. Can be used to test the format of the response without actually running the query.

E.g.:

```
SET FMTONLY ON
GO
select * from my my_table
GO
SET FMTONLY OFF
GO
```

Will produce an empty result set.

---

In C#, with an `SqlCommand` object, you can specify the `SchemaOnly` [`CommandBehaviour`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior.aspx) and you'll similarly get an empty result set that you can then examine.

Comment: Accepting the information re C# API...exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks, Damien!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might get use out of this:

```
EXEC sp_help my_table
```

Or see my question/answer here: [How do I get a list of columns in a table or view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687112/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-columns-in-a-table-or-view)

Comment: I'd have assumed "arbitrary SQL/prepared statement/stored procedure" would be intended to cover more than a single table.