# How do I investigate created a table syntax in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

How do I investigate the code that created the table? This is for the purpose of finding out if a column in a table contains aggregate information of other columns or is a column found somewhere else.

Comment: Try `exec sp_columns OwallabyTable`. [[related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319354/what-is-the-equivalent-of-describe-table-in-sql-server)]

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to find out the table information  use the below scripts..

```
SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
       , IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'

SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'

SELECT name, type_desc, is_unique, is_primary_key
FROM sys.indexes
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableName')
```